# Open Street Map Bug

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am teaching myself QGIS 3.12 and am trying to use XYZ tiles, but dragging in Google Sat or OpenStreetMap yields a sea of blue.

I have tried layering it in different spots, but it doesn't make a difference.

I have tried restarting QGIS, and tried downloading the Quick Map Services plugin, but that only crashes and shuts down the application.

The weirdest part - when I zoom far out, it displays Turkey far off of the coast of Angola, and unimaginably small. I tried it with Bolivia, Peru, and Albania, and the location is all the same. Is this an issue with my XYZ tiles, my scale, my coordinate system, me?

Comment: what projection are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

#### OpenStreetMap out of the box

OpenStreetMap tiles are available in QGIS out of the box.

Just double click on OpenStreetMap, under XYZ Tiles on the browser panel.

Opening QGIS, and with just two clicks you should see the world.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your response, but it does not let me click this. Please advise!

Comment: @SabinaSethiUnni In QGIS, go to Settings, User Profiles and select New Profile... and named it something. This ensures that you start with just the default settings, without any plugins. Then, on Browser panel, just double click OpenStreetMap. (If Browser is not visible, enable it in View → Panels → Browser).